# How to write a query to compare among objects from json object array in Postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, duplicates, jsonb, json-arrayagg

I have a column as jsonb in PostgreSQL which can have the below json array references:

```json
[
  {
    "endTime": {
      "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY",
      "timeOfDay": {
        "hours": 14,
        "minutes": 30
      }
    },
    "skillCode": "1000124",
    "startTime": {
      "dayOfWeek": "TUESDAY",
      "timeOfDay": {
        "hours": 9,
        "minutes": 0
      }
    },
    "premiumBreak": {
      "hours": 0,
      "minutes": 0
    },
    "standardBreak": {
      "hours": 0,
      "minutes": 30
    }
  },
  {
    "endTime": {
      "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
      "timeOfDay": {
        "hours": 14,
        "minutes": 30
      }
    },
    "skillCode": "1000176",
    "startTime": {
      "dayOfWeek": "WEDNESDAY",
      "timeOfDay": {
        "hours": 9,
        "minutes": 0
      }
    },
    "premiumBreak": {
      "hours": 0,
      "minutes": 0
    },
    "standardBreak": {
      "hours": 0,
      "minutes": 30
    }
  },
  {
    "endTime": {
      "dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY",
      "timeOfDay": {
        "hours": 14,
        "minutes": 30
      }
    },
    "skillCode": "1000176",
    "startTime": {
      "dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY",
      "timeOfDay": {
        "hours": 9,
        "minutes": 0
      }
    },
    "premiumBreak": {
      "hours": 0,
      "minutes": 0
    },
    "standardBreak": {
      "hours": 0,
      "minutes": 30
    }
  }
]
```

I have 10k+ records and have to fetch records based on the below criteria :

Records which has this array objects which has->
Same "endTime", "startTime" but different "skillCode".

How to write a query to get lists of all records having the above criteria.

What I have done :

1. I am able to get records based on the json object array column based on one key.

SELECT
*
FROM
table t
WHERE
EXISTS (
SELECT
*
FROM
jsonb_array_elements(t.column) AS jsond
WHERE (jsond ->> 'skillCode')::int = 1000128);

2. But not able to get how to compare the objects among themselves like we put over a loop and check-in Java code.

Comment: Don't store tabular data in a JSON.

Comment: It's already there. Legacy application. Can't change schema now :(